# Non-linear correlation

Tags: list-manipulation, nonlinear, correlation

This may be a more mathematics question. There is also a coding issue.

I would like to test non-linear correlation of two vectors

Maybe I have overlooked a function that already does this, although my attempt:

```
ClearAll["Global'*"]
a = Table[Accumulate[RandomReal[{-1, 1}, 20]], {2}];

b2 = Sort /@ ({Flatten[Position[MinDetect[a[[2]]], 1]], 
     Flatten[Position[MaxDetect[a[[2]]], 1]]}~Flatten~{2})
c2 = Transpose@{Range[%[[#, 1]], %[[#, -1]]], 
     a[[2, %[[#, 1]] ;; %[[#, -1]]]]} & /@ Range[Length[%]]
d2 = Fit[%[[#]], {1, x}, x] & /@ Range[Length[%]]
e2 = Table[%[[#]], {x, b2[[#, 1]], b2[[#, -1]]}] & /@ Range[Length[d2]]
f2 = Transpose@{Range[b2[[#, 1]], b2[[#, -1]]], e2[[#]]} & /@ 
  Range[Length[b2]]

b1 = Sort /@ ({Flatten[Position[MinDetect[a[[1]]], 1]], 
     Flatten[Position[MaxDetect[a[[1]]], 1]]}~Flatten~{2})
c1 = Transpose@{Range[%[[#, 1]], %[[#, -1]]], 
     a[[1, %[[#, 1]] ;; %[[#, -1]]]]} & /@ Range[Length[%]]
d1 = Fit[%[[#]], {1, x}, x] & /@ Range[Length[%]]
e1 = Table[%[[#]], {x, b1[[#, 1]], b1[[#, -1]]}] & /@ Range[Length[d1]]
f1 = Transpose@{Range[b1[[#, 1]], b1[[#, -1]]], e1[[#]]} & /@ 
  Range[Length[b1]]

Show[ListLinePlot[f2[[#]]] & /@ Range[Length[f2]],
 ListLinePlot[f1[[#]], PlotStyle -> Red] & /@ Range[Length[f1]]
 , PlotRange -> All]
```

```
Show[
 ListLinePlot[a, Filling -> Axis, PlotLegends -> {"one", "two"}],
 ListPlot[MaxDetect[a]*a, PlotStyle -> Red]
 ]
```

[image]

Where I'd like to take a linear segment between the local min & max, and find the correlation between segments (only using alternate segments for ease)

[image]

I have made a wrong turn and when I run the correlation I get a perfect 1 for all..

```
corr1 = Table[
  d2[[1]], {x, b2[[1, 1]], b2[[1, -1]], 
   Abs[b2[[1, 1]] - b2[[1, -1]]]/Max[b1[[1]], b2[[1]]]}]
corr2 = Table[
  d1[[1]], {x, b1[[1, 1]], b1[[1, -1]], 
   Abs[b1[[1, 1]] - b1[[1, -1]]]/Max[b1[[1]], b2[[1]]]}]
```

```
Correlation[corr1, corr2]
out[1]: 1.
```

Comment: b and d are not defined. The code does not run.

Comment: @DanielHuber Oops they should be b1 and d1, it should work now

Comment: The correlation is minus 1 what makes sense if you plot  the 3 points of corr1 and corr2.  The middle point is the mean. Therefore, after subtracting the mean,  you have: {-y,0,y}. The difference in the magnitude of y between corr1 and corr2 is taken care by dividing by the standard deviation. So you have: {-y,0,y} and {y,0,-y} for some y.

Comment: Would you explain what you mean by "test non-linear correlation"?  Usually a "test" means that you have sample data and want to see if the parameter that generates the data is a certain value (or is higher or lower than a certain value).  But you haven't defined the underlying parameter:  only the estimator of an the undefined parameter.

Comment: @JimB Apologies, yeah there's no test. Effectively calculating a correlation coefficient, in the same way the Pearson's correlation coefficient the linear similarity of two vectors, however for non linear vectors

Comment: I see.  You might consider asking the question about existing definitions of correlation at https://stats.stackexchange.com/.